# how to insert checkout page custom field value wp_posts table in wp

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have added the custom field check out page. I want to add this custom field's value to the order list in the wp_posts table
Here I have added a Row delivery_option in wp_posts table

http://prntscr.com/rbdjcy

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

in WP you dont need/shouldn't change wp tables are this will be overwritten in the next update/upgrade. To save those values use WP php functions (forget database as WP functions will handle saving/getting for you from meta table)

So to add or update use

`update_post_meta($post_id, $meta_key, $meta_val);`

here meta key will be "delivery_option" and meta_value will be anything you want to store. $post_id will be current post/product id , you can get as `get_the_ID();`  Also if you do not want this custom field show up in WP default custom fields metaboxes, you may prefix your meta key with "_" underscore so `"delivery_option"` will be become `"_delivery_option"`

Then to get this data back :

```
$delivery_val = get_post_meta($post_id, 'delivery_option', true);
```

or 
`$delivery_val = get_post_meta($post_id, '_delivery_option', true);` //_used to keep it hidden from WP default custom fields metaboxes

Source:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_post_meta/
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_post_meta/

PS. Even there is add_post_meta , normally we use update_post_meta as it will add if no value exists or will update if any old value exists.